# Scream vs. Shout

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

When I see someone doing mischief, I will **shout** at the person so that he/she will notice that I see him/her doing something not right, to stop him/her from doing whatever he/she is doing.

When I see a ghost, I **scream** out loud, out of surprise.

For the first case, would it be correct to use **rufen**?

What about the second case? There's **schreien** and **kreischen**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the first case, would it be correct to use rufen?

No, rufen is to talk loud but neutral to make someone hear it from a distance. What you mean is more like "schreien" or "brüllen", this has a negative impression.
But both isn't nice by the way, you can tell someone he did wrong in a normal way which will be more effective ;-)

> What about the second case? There's schreien and kreischen...

These words cannot be clearly separated. I would rate that way.

- Rufen: often neutral, not much emotion. Loud talking to make someone hear it due to distance or noise. But you can "um Hilfe rufen" = yell/scream for help.
- Schreien: Babys do that. People who are upset do that. People who just talk loud do that too. It depends on the context if it's negative or not. If you yell at someone it is "anschreien". The more pain or fear is in the situation, the more you tend to use "schreien" than "rufen".
- Kreischen: Typically higher pitch and awkward to hear. In german this verb is also used for things like a buzz saw :-)

Comment: Rufen ist nicht laut reden. Das ist Unfug. Rufe sind kurz und impulsiv.

Comment: @user unknown Rufen impliziert einen gewissen Inhalt im gerufenen während schreien auch inhaltslos sein kann.

Comment: Einerseits kann man auch "Ey" oder "Ho" rufen, andererseits war das nicht mein Punkt. Wenn jemand "Feuer" oder "Ho" ruft ist das kein Reden.

Comment: Wie könnte man es passender sagen als "reden"?